# Partially Bold Text in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a tableView which has cells populated by two arrays :

```
var names = ["Marie : ", "Nicolas : " , "Sarah : "]

var colors = ["White" , "Blue" , "Red"]
```

My cells are populated by my arrays in a single UILabel named "info" :

```
cell.info.text = names[indexPath.row] + colors[indexPath.row]
```

Everything works fine, I just don't manage to have my "names" array to appear in **bold** without touching to the "colors" array.

What would be the best approach to do this ?

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the names to appear in bold, use the `UILabel` `attributedText` attribute to set an attributed string instead of a plain text string.

Something like:

```
let name = names[indexPath.row]
let color = colors[indexPath.row]
let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: name, attributes:[NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize:15)])
attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string:color))
cell.info.attributedText = attributedText
```

Of course, you'd need to set the font in the above for the bold part according to how you have the cell styled.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer ! It seems that this method can only be used with simple strings. Tell me if I'm wrong. I didn't find any example of this method used with arrays of strings.

Comment: An array of Strings would still work the same as a String here since you simply extract one value from the array - not display the whole array :) So it should not make any difference. I will modify my code above to use your data to show how it can be done.

Comment: You are assigning attributed text to text property when it should be to the attributedText property

Comment: @LeoDabus Just noticed that and fixed that as you were typing your comment - thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for the help !! I will try this asap and get back to you

Comment: @Fahim You can't append it like that you need to break it into 2 lines. `let attributedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: name, attributes:[NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)])`

Comment: and `attributedText.append(NSAttributedString(string: color))`

Comment: @LeoDabus You are right, just tested the code and the chaining does not work. Will change my answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Fahim you saved my day :D

Comment: Happy to have been of help, @JonathanLD